# Calling ShowDialog() causes an ArgumentNullException because BindingManager.Current is null?

Tags: c#, winforms

I inherited (as these things go) an application that's based on WinForms.
It's a plugin to another software, they give us the IWin32Window-Handle that we set as the owner to our own Form.

When we call `ShowDialog(windowHandle)` however we get an exception with [this callstack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMbto.png). Somehow I wasn't able to debug into the very internals of WinForms but I took a look at the last WinForms method that is being called, so at least I know what is null:

```cs
internal void SetBindingManagerBase(BindingManagerBase lManager) {
    if (bindingManager == lManager)
    {
        return;
    }
 
    // remove notification from the backEnd
    if (bindingManager != null && fieldInfo != null && bindingManager.IsBinding && !(bindingManager is CurrencyManager)) {
        fieldInfo.RemoveValueChanged(bindingManager.Current, new EventHandler(PropValueChanged));
        fieldInfo = null;
    }
 
    this.bindingManager = lManager;
    CheckBinding();
}
```

(It's `bindingManager.Current`).

Does anyone here have any clue what can cause this? I am not very knowledgeable about WinForms and I didn't change anything that can explain this behavior, maybe something changed on the end of the Software that we're writing the plugin for (only happens with the latest version)? Is there any way to check the Form's bindings before `ShowDialog()` is called to find out which Control/Binding is causing this?